# jquery input text convert to image

Tags: jquery, input

I have this input text code:

```
$("#text1").keyup(function() {
    $('#text2').text($('#text1').val());
});
$('#text2').draggable({
    containment: 'parent'
});
```

Question: how to convert it to image in jquery?

Comment: how to convert what? what are trying to achieve?

Comment: @Elen convert that text. I think it has to be an image first, because once it be came an image, I want to add class and with other images i will capture it in php.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the question correctly, you want to convert a piece of text to an image.

Use a [`<canvas>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Canvas) tag to render text, and then call [`toDataURL()`](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#dom-canvas-todataurl) to get a base64 representation of the image data.

Comment: Show some effort. Read the docs. Try writing some of your own code, and come back when you have a specific problem with a particular step. [Stack Overflow is not a Code Writing, Tutorial or Consulting Service.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128553/133242)